# Google maps v3 draggable marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm new in google maps, and I'm trying to learn it.

```js
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
     map:map,
     draggable:true,
     animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
     position: results[0].geometry.location
});
```

This is my marker position, when I'm initialising the marker position than I know the place name (for example: XY street, New York,), but because of the draggable option it is changing, and my question is how can I get the new place name, what event handler do I need.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```js
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    map:map,
    draggable:true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() 
{
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
});

function geocodePosition(pos) 
{
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   geocoder.geocode
    ({
        latLng: pos
    }, 
        function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                $("#mapSearchInput").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                $("#mapErrorMsg").hide(100);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $("#mapErrorMsg").html('Cannot determine address at this location.'+status).show(100);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Source [The Wizz.art](https://www.thewizz.art/2022/01/03/how-to-get-the-location-name-when-the-marker-is-dragged-and-dropped-on-google-maps/)

Comment: what is the "dragend" and where it used? I copied your code and run but I can't print status or result inside the function.

Comment: dragend is an event that is triggered by the google maps API. This is listening for the what to do when the marker is dropped back onto the map.

Comment: @ohlala Your code worked fine for me, but the address in `#mapSearchInput` is not according to my requirements, like if i drop the marker on a shop its not displaying shop name but showing street address without shop name. Plz help

Comment: `marker.getPosition()` sometimes gave incorrect coordinates, especially over the river

Answer (score 29):

**Set a Position on Map using lat/lang and make the marker draggable**

- Using lat/lang initially sets a marker at the given point on the map
- The address variable is used for title purpose. It can be ignored.
- *draggable:true* makes the marker draggable.
- Use event listener *google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker)* To listen for changes in the marker position

  ```
  function showMap(lat,lang,address) {
  var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lang};

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: myLatLng
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: address,
        draggable:true,
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker){
          var latLng = marker.latLng; 
          currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
          currentLongitude = latLng.lng();
          jQ("#latitude").val(currentLatitude);
          jQ("#longitude").val(currentLongitude);
       }); 
  }
  ```

Comment: ^^ Please note the stray curly brace outside the code area. I tried to change it, but no matter what I tried I couldn't get the to code mark-up to work correctly on this answer. Anyone know why? Can someone else fix it?

Answer (score 7):

```js
/**
 *Receiving the value of text box and type done conversion by Number() 
 */
var latitude = Number(document.getElementById("la").value);
var longitude = Number(document.getElementById("lo").value);

function initMap() {
  /**
   *Passing the value of variable received from text box
   **/
  var uluru = {
    lat: latitude,
    lng: longitude
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: uluru
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: uluru
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
    function(marker) {
      currentLatitude = marker.position.lat();
      currentLongitude = marker.position.lng();
      $("#la").val(currentLatitude);
      $("#lo").val(currentLongitude);
    }
  );
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
Latitude <input type="text" id="la" name="latitude" value="28.39"> Longitude<input type="text" id="lo" name="longitude" value="84.12">

<!--Google Map API Link-->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&callback=initMap">
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code which gets drag-able marker with position in text box:

```js
/**
 *Receiving the value of text box and type done conversion by Number() 
 */
var latitude = Number(document.getElementById("la").value);
var longitude = Number(document.getElementById("lo").value);

function initMap() {
  /**
   *Passing the value of variable received from text box
   **/
  var uluru = {
    lat: latitude,
    lng: longitude
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: uluru
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    position: uluru
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend',
    function(marker) {
      var latLng = marker.latLng;
      currentLatitude = latLng.lat();
      currentLongitude = latLng.lng();
      $("#la").val(currentLatitude);
      $("#lo").val(currentLongitude);
    }
  );
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
Latitude <input type="text" id="la" name="latitude" value="28.39"> Longitude<input type="text" id="lo" name="longitude" value="84.12">

<!--Google Map API Link-->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEYHERE&callback=initMap">
```

Please Use jQuery at the head

Comment: Please fix the formatting of this code in markdown. Just put it in a single code tag to save space